# How do I create a tag using resource method in boto3 aws lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3

I am trying to create a tag using ec2.resource method NOT ec2.CLIENT... I can create it with client but trying to figure out with resource. I am getting an error **"errorMessage": "'dict' object has no attribute 'create_tags'"**. I have provided my code. I am comparing certain tag which I am using if statement but when I use create_tag method I get an error.

```
    import boto3
    import collections
    import sys
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name='us-east-2')
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
    vol = ec2.Volume(id='1256')
    for delV in vol.tags:
    delV.create_tags(Tags=[{'Key':'Name', 'Value':'Test1'}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you don't need to iterate over the existing tags like you are doing;

```
import boto3
import collections
import sys
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',region_name='us-east-2')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    my_list_of_ids = [1256, 1234, 2300]
    for volid in my_list_of_ids:
        vol = ec2.Volume(id=volid)
        for tag in vol.tags:
          if tag['Name'] == 'Name' and tag['Value'] == Value:
            print("Exists")
        vol.create_tags(Tags=[{'Key':'Name', 'Value':'Test1'}])
```

Comment: No it's not going to work this way. I am trying to loop through few volume ids... when I use a loop, i get an error see the code below -   for delV in vol.tags:
    delV.create_tags(Tags=[{'Key':'Name', 'Value':'Test1'}])

Comment: How about this then to loop through your list of volume ids and create the tag on each?

Comment: so are you saying define my_list_of_ids =  ec2.Volume(id='1256').. is it equivalent to my above code :- vol = ec2.Volume(id='1256')

Comment: No, my_list_of_ids should be a list of the volume ids that you want to create tags for, ex:  my_list_of_ids = [1256, 1234, 2300] to create tags for volumes that have the specified ids.

Comment: thanks for the help. I am new to lambda boto3. Do you suggest any tutorial or good sites that will cover it

Comment: There are tons of tutorials online, not any I'd recommend specifically but the good thing is that there are many available.

Comment: Now the problem is I can use if statement to see if there is any tag exist or not 
if delV['Key'] == 'Name':
           
if delV['Value'] == 'Test1'
Print("Exist")
i get an error

Comment: I don't understand why do I get an error if i add tag.delete_volume(VolumeId=vol)... "errorMessage": "'dict' object has no attribute 'delete_volume'",... What is the purpose or what is it asking me to do.. what am i looking for to solve it.. Can you please provide me little more details so i can understand it n do it going forward

Comment: I got it that's the answer:-  vol.delete()